Error: Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further
CocoaPods Installation Issue: Missing Keys and OpenSSL Trouble
Here's the problem:

As trying to install CocoaPods dependencies, but something went wrong.
It turned out you needed a plugin called cocoapods-keys
Installing cocoapods-keys  throws the error of "While executing gem OpenSSL is not available and install OpenSSL" while it's already installed into my device.
The current issue was OpenSSL version isn't compatible with cocoapods-keys
Downgrading OpenSSL to a compatible version is risky due to some security reasons.
The compatible version (OpenSSL 1.0) isn't even available on our current operating system.[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/Mu2aiBpB.png)

I tried installing reinstalling pod again.
Also tried to update and downgrade the library as the requirements
